# Uncaught exception 'Firebase\JWT\BeforeValidException' with message 'Cannot handle token prior to 2016-11-03T21:37:13+0100'

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

Hello I have a problem trying to use google/apiclient

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Firebase\JWT\BeforeValidException'
>   with message 'Cannot handle token prior to 2016-11-03T21:37:13+0100'
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\Google\vendor\firebase\php-jwt\src\JWT.php:124
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Google\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\AccessToken\Verify.php(100):
>   Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode('eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...', '-----BEGIN PUBL...',
>   Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Google\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(705):
>   Google_AccessToken_Verify->verifyIdToken('eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...',
>   '474251646530-0t...') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Google\app\class\google_auth.php(51):
>   Google_Client->verifyIdToken() #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Google\app\class\google_auth.php(35):
>   GoogleAuth->getPayLoad() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Google\index.php(10):
>   GoogleAuth->checkRedirectCode() #5 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Google\vendor\firebase\php-jwt\src\JWT.php on line 124

My index:

```
<?php
    require_once('app/ini.php');
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    require_once('app/class/google_auth.php');


    $googleClient = new Google_Client();
    $auth = new GoogleAuth($googleClient);

    if ($auth->checkRedirectCode()) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php if (!$auth->isLoggedIn()): //Verificar Inicio de Sesion ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $auth->getAuthUrl(); ?>">Inicie Sesion con Google</a>
    <?php else: //Si no ha iniciado Sesion ?>
        Bienvenido.. <a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesion</a>
    <?php endif; ?> 

</body>
</html>
```

The class GoogleAuth:

```
<?php

    class GoogleAuth{//Clase para la autenticacion del usuario google

        protected $client;//Variable de cliente

        public function __construct(Google_Client $googleClient = null){
            $this->client = $googleClient;

            if ($this->client) {

                $this->client->setClientId('474251646530-0tiho0cbf4dusercontent.com');//Usuario Auth Google
                $this->client->setClientSecret('bMuLusxvnvPg2zRz');//Clave Auth Google
                $this->client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/Google/index.php');
                $this->client->setScopes('email');

            }
        }

        public function isLoggedIn(){//Metodo que devuelve el estatus de la Sesion con Google (true o false)
            return isset($_SESSION['access_token']);

        }

        public function getAuthUrl(){//Funcion que devuelve el enlace requerido para iniciar sesion
            return $this->client->createAuthUrl();

        }

        public function checkRedirectCode(){
            if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
                $this->client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
                $this->setToken($this->client->getAccessToken());

                $payload=$this->getPayLoad();
                echo "<pre>", print_r($payload) ,"<pre>";
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public function setToken($token){
            $_SESSION['access_token']=$token;
            $this->client->setAccessToken($token);
        }

        public function logout(){
            unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
        }

        public function getPayLoad(){
            $payload=$this->client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();
            return $payload;
        }

    }

?>
```

PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: now i have this error 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributes() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\Google\app\class\google_auth.php on line 52 in the same code

Answer (score 9):

The JWT library makes use of a leeway (in seconds) to account for when there is a clock skew times between the signing and verifying servers.

This error occurs when the times difference between library and your server is major than the leeway

To fix it, go to

> \vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\AccessToken\Verify.php

and increase leeway in the *getJwtService* function.

```
private function getJwtService()
  {
    $jwtClass = 'JWT';
    if (class_exists('\Firebase\JWT\JWT')) {
      $jwtClass = 'Firebase\JWT\JWT';
    }

    if (property_exists($jwtClass, 'leeway')) {
      // adds 1 second to JWT leeway
      // @see https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/827
      $jwtClass::$leeway += 10;
    }

    return new $jwtClass;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a Server time issue. The time between your JWT Library and Server differs. That Library uses the 'UTC' timezone. Depending on your usecase, you will want to align the timezones to be in the same zone or you can comment this line if you don't need it.

```
// Configures the time that the token can be used (nbf claim)
// ->setNotBefore(time() + 60)
```

Comment: That line does not exist anywhere in OP's code. I assume the question has been edited ? If not, where is that line supposed to be at ?

Comment: @Taurus That line is in the configuration object where you set the Issuer, setAudience etc  https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/tree/3.2

Comment: I only ever use 3 lines of code related to tokens and Google: `$CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";

$id_token = $_POST["id"];

$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);

$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);`. I am not really good at server-side but i wonder what i would set these things for (issuer, setAudience, etc...) ?

Comment: those values are identifiers and a form of security checks in some cases.

Comment: But if they are checked for by `JWT.php`, doesn't it mean they are already set ?

Comment: I believe they have default values, but you can change it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside this function:

```
public function getPayLoad(){
    $payload=$this->client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();
    return $payload;
}
```

remove `getAttributes()` and leave it like this:

```
public function getPayLoad(){
    $payload=$this->client->verifyIdToken();
    //print_r($payload); //This gives you the information you need
    return $payload;
}
```